# OpenSuse - Error adding repository

Tags: opensuse

When I try to add a repository in a new opensuse installation this error appears, what can it be?

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo

File '/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo' not found on medium 'https://download.opensuse.org/'
```

Comment: It's a 404 error.

Comment: I want to add repositories to install packages like python3, php7. What repositories can I use?